# How big of a Dataset can ELKI handle?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining, dbscan, elki

I have 100,000 points that I would like to cluster using the OPTICS algorithm in ELKI. I have a upper triangular distance matrix of about 5 billion entries for this point set. In the format that ELKI wants the matrix, it will take about 100GB in memory. I am wondering does ELKI handle that sort of data load? Can any one confirm if you have made this work before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I frequently use ELKI with 100k points, up to 10 million.

However, for this to be fast you **should use indexes**.

For obvious reasons, *any* dense matrix based approach will scale at best `O(n^2)`, and need `O(n^2)` memory. Which is why I cannot process these data sets with R or Weka or scipy. They usually first try to compute the full distance matrix, and either fail halfway through, or run out of memory halfway through, or fail with negative allocation size (Weka, when your data set overflows the 2^31 positive integers, i.e. is around 46k objects).

In the binary format, with float precision, the ELKI matrix format should be around `100000*999999/2*4 + 4` bytes, maybe add another 4 bytes for size information. This is **20 GB**.
If you use the "easy to use" ascii format, then it will indeed be more. But if you use gzip compression it may end up being about the same size. It's common to have gzip compress such data to 10-20% of the raw size. In my experience **gzip compressed ascii can be as small as binary encoded doubles**.
The main benefit of the binary format is that it will actually reside on disk, and memory caching will be handled by your operating system.

Either way, I **recommend to not compute distance matrixes at all in the first place**.

Because if you decide to go from 100k to 1 million, the raw matrix would grow to 2 TB, and when you go to 10 million it will be 200 TB. If you want double precision, double that.

If you are using distance matrixes, your method *will* be at best `O(n^2)`, and thus not scale. Avoiding computing all pairwise distances in the first place is an important speed factor.

I use **indexes** for everything. For kNN or radius bound approaches (for OPTICS, use the epsion parameter to make indexes effective! Choose a low epsilon!) you can precompute these queries once, if you are going to need them repeatedly.

On a data set I frequently use, with 75k instances and 27 dimensions, the file storing the precomputed 101 nearest neighbors + ties, with double precision, is 81 MB (note: this can be seen as a sparse similarity matrix). By using an index for precomputing this cache, it takes just a few minutes to compute; and then I can ran most kNN based algorithms such as **LOF on this 75k dataset in 108 ms** (+262 ms for loading the kNN cache + parsing the raw input data 2364 ms, for a total runtime of 3 seconds; dominated by parsing double values).

Comment: What type of index would you recommend for OPTICS/DBSCAN ?

Comment: Depends on the dimensionality, distance function, and selectivity. Cover trees work very well for most metrics, but for low-dimensional Euclidean data, R*-trees (with STR bulk loading) as well as k-d-trees can work well, too.